# Maximum difference in an Array not passing all test cases in HackerRank

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, kotlin

I applied for a job, and the prospective employer sent me the following HackerRank problem, which cannot be found in the public area.

Give an array of integers, compute the maximum difference between any item and any lower indexed smaller item for all possible pairs. In other words, for the array `arr`, find the maximum value of `arr[j] - arr[i]` for all i, j where `0 <= i < j < n` and `arr[i] < arr[j]`. If no item has a smaller item with a lower index, then return `-1`.

For example, given `arr = [1,2,6,4]`, first compare 2 to the elements to its left. 1 is smaller, so calculate the difference `2 - 1 = 1`. 6 is bigger than 2 and 1, so calculate the difference `6 - 2 = 4` and `6 - 1 = 5`. The last element, 4, is only bigger than 2 and 1, and the difference are `4 - 2 = 2` and `4 - 1 = 3`. The largest difference is `6 - 1 = 5`.

**Function Description**

Complete the function `maxDifference`. The function must return an integer that represents the maximum difference in `arr`.

`maxDifference` has the following parameter(s):
`arr[arr[0], arr[1],...arr[n-1]]`: an array of integers.

**Constraints**

- 1 <= n <= 2*10^5
- -10^6 <= arr[i] <= 10^6 where [0, n-1]

**Solution**

```
fun maxDifference(arr: Array<Int>): Int {

    var min: Pair<Int, Int> = Pair(0, 0)
    var max: Pair<Int, Int> = Pair(0, 0)
    var result = -1

    for(i in 0 until arr.size) {
        when {
            i == 0 -> {
                min = Pair(i, arr[i])
                max = Pair(i, arr[i])
            }
            min.second > arr[i] -> min = Pair(i, arr[i])
            max.second < arr[i] -> max = Pair(i, arr[i])
        }

        if(max.first > min.first && max.second > min.second)
            result = kotlin.math.max(result, max.second - min.second)
    }

    return result
}
```

**The problem**

For some reason solution above not passing all test cases in the [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/).
Unfortunately employer who sent this test not willing to disclose test cases to see where is the issue. 
The code itself works correct.

**Test cases**

1. [2,3,10,2,4,8,1] - (expected result is 8)
2. [7,9,5,6,3,2] - (expected result is 2)
3. [3] - (expected result is -1)
4. [-3, -2] - (expected result is 1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325848/4964822) by **@Tom** about failing tests, I feel your solution is rather complicated since you try to maintain a pair. I have simplified this as below(Not a **kotlin dev**, so below is in Javascript):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 6, 4];

var min = arr[0];
var diff = -1;

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  if (arr[i] > min) diff = Math.max(arr[i] - min, diff);
  min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
}

console.log(diff);
```

- Well, the conditions say that `0 <= i < j < n` and `arr[i] < arr[j]`. This calls for a greedy approach which points us towards the fact that we just need to maintain the `min` value when we move from left to right in the array.
- Just maintaining the `min` value takes us in the correct path because there would be several `arr[i]` less than the current `arr[j]`, but taking the minimum among all previous `i` for the current `arr[j]` will obviously give us the maximum difference.

Comment: Thanks for the better solution! I got where is my bug. Here is updated code https://gist.github.com/atonamy/a3800fdf89e06bf726b1a16f1a6a5601
But yours one is more elegant and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Your init is wrong - you should hardcode min/max to ±10<sup>6</sup>
Also isn't min/max useless ? Should not you work with min/max of difference ?
Example here should be 4 - 3 = 1, but not found (suppose your code work exactly same as this):

```js
function maxDifference(arr) {
    var min = [0,0];
    var max = [0,0];
    var result = -1

    for(var i in arr) {
        if(i == 0) {
            min = [i, arr[i]];
            max = [i, arr[i]];
        }
        if(min[1] > arr[i]) min = [i, arr[i]];
        if(max[1] < arr[i]) max = [i, arr[i]];

        if(max[0] > min[0] && max[1] > min[1])
            result = Math.max(result, max[1] - min[1])
    }

    return result
}
var a = prompt("Enter data:","9,7,5,6,3,4");
console.log("Array:",a);
console.log(maxDifference(a.split(',')));
```

Comment: Also 7,9,5,6,3,9 returns 2, but should not be 6 ?

Comment: Why does `9,7,5,6,3,4` return `-1` in your case? Shouldn't it be `1`?

Comment: It is just translation - not any fix - meant to test/find possibly failed TCs.

Comment: Ohh, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
fun maxiDiff(numbers:List<Int>):Int{
    
    val numbersSorted = numbers.distinct().sorted()
    
    if(numbersSorted.isEmpty() || numbersSorted.size == 1)return -1
    
    val gaps = numbersSorted.zipWithNext{a,b -> Math.abs(b-a)}
    
    return gaps.max() ?: -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this question in python:

```
for i in range(t):
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
imax = max(a)
imin = min(a)
print(imax-imin)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is wrong since the min has to come before max and you don't make sure that with this code. For example, If ```imax``` is the first element in the array, then you should look for another pair to find  the maximum difference.